# PyQt: setContextMenu doesn't work while there is a loop in the thread

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pyqt

I am making a `QtGui.QMenu()` in my tray icon and adding an action into it: `.addAction("Close", lambda : exit(1))` so when I click on my tray icon I could exit the application quickly:

[image]

The problem begins when I am making a loop inside my `QtCore.QThread`, for some reason the context menu stops working (I cant even see it, nothing happends while right-clicking the tray icon). So the question is - what is the problem any why is the loop hanging out the thread like that?

The code (**simply remove the loop comments in the `__init__` function to reproduce the problem**):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Main(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

        self.createTrayIcon()

        self.trayIcon.show()
        self.trayIcon.showMessage("Hello", u"This is a description.")

        # while True:
        #   self.doSomething()
        #   time.sleep(2)

    def createTrayIcon(self):
        self.trayIconMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.trayIconMenu.addAction("Close", lambda : exit(1))

        self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.trayIcon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(r"t_icon.png"))
        self.trayIcon.setToolTip("Tooltip")
        self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)

    def doSomething(self):
        print "Doing something"

mainThread = Main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually starting a new thread with your current design. You're creating a `QThread` object, which builds a tray icon and shows it in the *main* thread of the process. So once you've shown the message `"Hello"`, you're blocking in the `while True` loop before you ever actually start the `app.exec_()` event loop. Without that event loop running, your icon won't respond to clicks.

To actually run code in a new thread, it has to be in the `run` method of the `QThreadObject`. The `run` method gets exeuted when you call `QThread.start()`. Here's an example that should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys 
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Main(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.doSomething()
            time.sleep(2)

    def doSomething(self):
        print "Doing something"


class MyIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self)
        self.trayIconMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.trayIconMenu.addAction("Close", lambda : exit(1))

        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(r"t_icon.png"))
        self.setToolTip("Tooltip")
        self.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)
        self.show()
        self.showMessage("Hello", u"This is a description.")

icon = MyIcon() # create the icon in the main thread
mainThread = Main() # build the thread object (it won't be running yet)
mainThread.start()  # run will be executed in a separate thread
sys.exit(app.exec_()) # Start the main loop, so the icon will respond to clicks.
```